# Is Azure TableStorageMembershipProvider really suitable to handle millions of users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-membership

Background - my understanding so far - 
Since all the membership data will be in the same partition, it is likely to cause long table scans after user-base has grown to millions.

Currently, I register users to my system based on an e-mail and password only. I also have a User table which resides on Azure SQL, and I keep the constraint between the two at the application level. The "foreign key" is the e-mail address.

Searching for users using the membership provider is done by email not by UserId/key.

Beside the homepage, the rest of the site required to be authenticated, therefore I expect the use of Membership will be significant, but not huge, since after authentication, the user is cached for a few minutes.

**Do you think that using  Membership-based Table-storage is generally a good practice for millions of users?**

**What would you recommend for my specific case?**

Comment: I'd recommend you not use a string as a foreign key if you expect such a load of data. Otherwise, the idea of cloud is scalability, so I'd naively presume they can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The membership provider is a 2005 .NET 2 relic that should be put out of its misery. It has no place in modern web architectures. Applications should work with claims-based authorisation and offload the identity to a service that is more capable. Look at [Azure ACS](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/), Azure Active Directory, [Thinktecture Identity Server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2), a combination of them all, or other token services.

If you are serious about being able to scale to millions of users then you need to think **really hard** about identity — because it is important. Using the membership provider will paint you into an architectural corner that is at odds with your ambitions.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, the table membership provider isn't officially supported and may not have been updated in some time. As a result, I'd be hesitant to use it for anything but the most basic demo purposes. Might I instead suggest looking at using Windows Azure Active Directory. This service is free of charge for basic identity management and can be easily integrated into an application. Windows Azure Active Directory is also the same solution used by Office 365 so it should meet your needs pretty handily.